# ArgumentError in select_tag on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to create a select_tag inside a form in rails, but when impelementar it shows me the following error: `wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 1..3)` What I want to do is implement the select with html attributes and the prompt. The method `cargarMaterias`, searches the database and returns an array of elements, its current impression is as follows:

```
["1-Sistemas de Informacion", "2-Programacion", "3-Matematicas", "4-Ingenieria Web"]
```

Oh, I forgot, the selected_tag is implemented as follows:

```
<%= select_tag :codigo_materia, Subject.cargarMaterias,{ prompt: "Seleccione la materia"}, {id: "EditboxCodigoMatHistMat", class: "EditBox"} %>
```

I've been doing the same thing for several hours, but I still can not solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> select_tag(name, option_tags = nil, options = {}) public

You should rewrite your [`select_tag`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag) as below

```
<%= select_tag :codigo_materia, Subject.cargarMaterias, { prompt: "Seleccione la materia", id: "EditboxCodigoMatHistMat", class: "EditBox"} %>
```

Both `options` and `html_options` should go as **last argument** to the `select_tag`. In other words, any other standard *HTML* keys also should be passed as `options`.

Further to simplify, it can be written as just

```
<%= select_tag :codigo_materia, Subject.cargarMaterias, prompt: "Seleccione la materia", id: "EditboxCodigoMatHistMat", class: "EditBox" %>
```

**Note:**

Your value for `option_tags` is **flawed**. It should be passed as `container` to [`options_for_select`](https://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select) like so

```
<%= select_tag :codigo_materia, options_for_select(Subject.cargarMaterias), prompt: "Seleccione la materia", id: "EditboxCodigoMatHistMat", class: "EditBox" %>
```